# Is Fidgeting good or not according to cognitive sciences?

Tags: psychology, body-language

I am searching through internet for the asked question. I read different articles and blogs, some says its is good for physical health and keep your BMI low and some say it is good activity.

But here my real concern is what a psychologist think about `Fidgeting`. Please give reference if possible.

Comment: Related: [Is leg jiggling a focus aid?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/241/21)

Comment: it is just about leg jiggling, and answers is not what i am seeking. Thanks any way